# reading z value from txt files with specific value of (x,y)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, file

i have txt file with x,y,z coordinates as follows:

```
x           y         z        another value
129.000000 -51.000000 3.192000 166 166 166
133.000000 -21.000000 6.982500 171 169 170
134.000000 -51.000000 8.379000 172 170 171
135.000000 -45.000000 8.379000 167 165 166
136.000000 -81.000000 8.578500 160 158 159
137.000000 -51.000000 9.376500 159 157 158
138.000000 -51.000000 9.576000 169 168 167
```

how to read the value of z when x=20,y=33?
I tried using `data = numpy.genfromtxt(yourFileName)` but it not worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

from io import StringIO

x = '''x           y         z    v1 v2 v3
129.000000 -51.000000 3.192000 166 166 166
133.000000 -21.000000 6.982500 171 169 170
134.000000 -51.000000 8.379000 172 170 171
135.000000 -45.000000 8.379000 167 165 166
136.000000 -81.000000 8.578500 160 158 159
137.000000 -51.000000 9.376500 159 157 158
138.000000 -51.000000 9.576000 169 168 167'''

out = StringIO(x ) 

df = pd.read_csv( out , delimiter="\s+"  )

print (df.query( "x==138 and y==-51"  ).z.values )
```

Comment: thank you, its work , is there another way to get z value if the text just contains numbers with "x y z v1 v2 v3?